# Impromptu .. with jquery 1.9 - error with browser.msie

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I get an error with impromptu ver 4.1 when running under the latest jquery 1.9

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

This was not the case with previous versions of jquery.

The offending line in impromptu is line 20:

```
var ie6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);
```

Comment: `jQuery.browser`: deprecated: 1.3, removed: 1.9

Comment: Aha ... so impromptu will break for everyone?

Comment: If that plugin depends on `browser` property, with jQuery 1.9, yes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could patch *Impromptu* replacing this line :

```
var ie6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);
```

... by this one :

```
var ie6 = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/6/) );
```

... so now it can work with jQuery v1.9.0+. Optionally, you could rollback to jQuery v1.8.3

**EDIT** (March 12th, 2013)

Thanks @johntrepreneur for your comments, you are correct. **Two notes**:

1. This edited line :

   ```
   var ie6 = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/6/) );
   ```

   ... should be replaced by this one :

   ```
   var ie6 = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6]/i) );
   ```

   ... my bad, I rushed writing the patch. That should do the trick.
2. *Impromptu* has completely removed IE6 support in their **[last commit](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu/commit/fe0dc99c92ca106c866c6a5b521c36ae43d50c9e)** (on March 25/2013 after this original post). The issue brought by the OP was that *Impromptu* did break with jQuery v1.9+ ... **updating the *Impromptu* js file to the [last version](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu) does also fix the issue**.

Comment: @undefined : I guess all related instances need to be patched as a workaround.

Comment: Yes, actually it only checks IE6. +1

Comment: @JFK your replacement line is not the same and incorrectly matches since it's finding any "6" in the userAgent string. I tested it in IE8 and your check matches (when it shouldn't) since the userAgent string has "msie" in it and a "6" somewhere else in it too: "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)".

Comment: But what does it return? true/false?

Comment: @SteveCav : If you are using IE6 the var `ie6` returns `true` otherwise `false`

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this one to target a range, will run code only on < IE9 & jQuery 1.9+

```
if (/msie [1-8]./.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ever since Jquery deprecated the $.browser funcionality
the easiest way that i found, was to create a global in javascript

```
var LTE_IE9 = false;
```

and the in use the condition HTML IE selectors

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script>LTE_IE9 = true;</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That's actually pretty clever.

Answer (score 0):

i use it.

```
  var browser = $.browser;
    if ( ! browser ) {
       var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
       var m = /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) || ! /compatible/.test(ua) && /(mozilla)/.exec( ua ) || [];
       browser = { version: m[2] };
       browser[ m[1] ] = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `Jquery migrate` plugin

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js

`$.browser.msie` removed from > jquery 1.9.X

Answer (score 0):

As said here, **$.browser** does not exist anymore in jQuery, since version **1.9**.

So check [browser.msie error after update to jQuery 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1)

Answer (score 0):

as $.browse is deprecated since jQuery V. 1.4 and removed in after jQuery V. 1.9

still you can fix this problem by these line of code(for all browser)

```
jQuery.browser = {};
jQuery.browser.mozilla = /mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && !/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.webkit = /webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.opera = /opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

Works fine for me;