# jQuery BBQ generates error with jQuery 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-bbq

jQuery BBQ noob question: I have downloaded jQuery BBQ 1.2.1 and I'm trying to use it with jQuery 2.1.0. BBQ works in the sense that it does what I want it to do, but I've noticed an error message in the console. I've tracked it down to what appears to be a compatibility issue. Here's a sample HTML page that produces the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        example
    </body>
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

In Firefox the console error is `TypeError: f is undefined`. In Chrome the error is different: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`.

I've noticed jQuery BBQ is pretty old. Is there a newer rev of jQuery BBQ? Or is there some newer replacement library?

UPDATE

I'm using jQuery BBQ because a google search sent me to this previously answered question: [Parsing URL hash/fragment identifier with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript). The real issue I'm trying to solve is the same as the linked question: to respond to changes in the hash portion of the URI and to parse that fragment.

It turns out that for my purposes (so far), I can eliminate jQuery BBQ and write a couple of lines of code to grab the hash string (and remove the hash sign):

```
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        var hashString = window.location.hash || '';
        hashString = hashString.replace("#",'');
        myEventHandler(hashString);
    });
```

So that will work for now. It's pretty simple and it's one less module dependency, so win-win. I suppose that's why there were no responses to a jQuery-BBQ question, eh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [browser.msie error after update to jQuery 1.9.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It would be a duplicate if the question had been asked by the jQuery-BBQ maintainer -- and apparently there isn't one. And while hand-patching a 3rd party component is not off the table, it's far simpler not to use jQuery-BBQ and instead use `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 3):

I am glad that your problem was solved(1 year ago!). But for anybody else who has this problem:

As you may have seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1) this problem is caused by $.browser which was deprecated in version 1.3 and removed in 1.9.

but you can fix that quite simply. just open jquery bbq source and search for f.msie (used like h = f.msie ) and replace it with:

```
( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? true : false
```

(now you must have `h = ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? true : false` )

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that worked for me was:

```
h = ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ? true : false)
```

or if used as part of an "if" switch...

```
 (h = ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ? true : false))
```