# menu_hover, JavaScript upgrading from jQuery 1.7 to jQuery 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am upgrading from jQuery 1.7 to jQuery 3.0

I am stuck updating the `menu_hover.js` file as jQuery 3 no longer supports `browser.msie`. It was dropped as of jQuery 1.9, and is no longer supported.

Can somebody please help me replace / redefine the following line?

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
```

here is the original `menu_hover.js` file:

```
$(function() {
   if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
   { 
     $('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').show();
     }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
     })
   }
});
```

Comment: Here is an alternative solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14892171/7237741

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme). 
This lets you migrate older jQuery code to jQuery 3.0+. You can add it to your script by using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>
```